# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1 address=0x90000008) when switching view controllers

Tags: iphone, ios, exc-bad-access

So, I have an app that uses a tableViewController to populate a list of different game types. When a game is selected, it performs a segue by that name.

This was working perfectly (pushing & popping correctly) until I added a stats menu for when one of the game modes finished.

Now I sometimes get a EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error when switching from the stats menu back to the tableViewController. So:

TVC ---> Game ---> Stats

*Then*

Stats ---> TVC

Code to switch from TVC to Game:

```
NSString* a = (NSString*)[games objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
a = [a stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:a sender:self];
```

Code to switch from Game to Stats Menu:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Stats" sender:self];
```

Code to switch from Stats Menu to TVC (Where the problem emerged):

```
NSArray* controllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
int a = [controllers count] - 1;
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:a-2] animated:YES];
```

[Error in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfhPw.png)

[Link to Code](http://pastie.org/4041828)

Comment: exec_bad_access tells us almost nothing except that an invalid object is trying to be accessed.  Are you using ARC?  Also do you have exception breakpoints enabled?

Comment: ARC is off, also what are exception breakpoints?

Comment: It's actually `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` (it's a mach exception)

Comment: See the first answer on this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212677/in-ios-5-1-app-why-cant-i-see-the-exception

Comment: @JasonCoco Yes, you are right!

Comment: Also make sure you have NSZombies enabled if you are not using ARC.  In Xcode 4:  Edit Scheme -> Diagnostics -> Enable Zombie Objects

Comment: Show some code, otherwise this is question is too arbitrary. It appears as if you are attempting to access a block of memory (from an NSArray perhaps?) that has been deallocated.

Comment: I switched it to ARC just so at least that way I have something that will complain if I mess up. Trying to reproduce again...

Comment: I added a link to my main code files. I'm going to stick with ARC for the moment since I don't seem to be experiencing this error with it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to analyze your code to see if there are any memory leak. It could be a cause that your application is crashing.

Comment: Switched to ARC to avoid alloc/release problems

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though apple is trying to enforce ARC now. I just downloaded the update for the 10.7 SDK and it made my program(which also contains a performSegueWithIdentifier:) super buggy and throw EXC_BAD_ACCESS on multiple issues that I had previously resolved(pre SDK update). I turned on ARC, and commented out all of my release/dealloc calls, its back to working condition. Nice how the debugger points you where they are i suppose. :)