# Cannot disallow editing UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am trying to complete a very simple task. Having a viewController where the user can choose to select an image from the camera och the gallery. I have done pretty much a copy-paste from AppCodas tutorial [here.](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-camera-iphone-app/)

The problem is that I don't want my users to be able to edit the photo because for some reason the photo gets clipped in a weird way when in landscape mode and I don't want a square picture. So what I am doing is this:

```
- (IBAction)takePhotoClicked:(id)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (IBAction)selectPhotoClicked:(id)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Very simply displaying the `UIImagePickerController` depending on the users choice, but it doesn't work with `picker.allowsEditing = NO;` because I get the error message: `Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.` when I open the imagePicker a second time and I get `nil`back from the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`.

Has anyone ever had the same issue?

Comment: I just used your code and it worked fine.

Comment: @Shabirjan Hi, which ios do you use?

Comment: no i just tested on UITableViewController and it work fine as well.

Comment: @Shabirjan Yup, I tested on a UIViewController and still doesn't work...

Comment: You can check below link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890003/uiimagepicker-get-error-snapshotting-a-view-that-has-not-been-rendered-results

May be it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the line "picker.allowsEditing = NO;" & Delete the App from Device & run it..

May be It

Comment: Sorry no is was not the case