# Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot in xamarin.ios7

Tags: ios7, xamarin.ios

When,I am capturing image from camera then it is giving error on console in ios7.I tried firstly without adding Thread.sleep(3000) in code but that was also not working.

complete error:
Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.

code:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.           

        PictureFromCameraButton.TouchUpInside += PictureFromCameraButton_Click;

    }

private void PictureFromCameraButton_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            Thread.Sleep (4000);                
                ImagePickerController.SetSourceType(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera);
    this.PresentViewController (ImagePickerController, true, null);


        } catch (NotSupportedException exception) {
            //Logging Exception in Flurry
            FA.Flurry.LogError(exception.GetType().Name,exception.Message,
                               new NSError(NSError.CocoaErrorDomain,3584));

            BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
                UIAlertView ErrorAlert = new UIAlertView ("Device unsupported", "Your device does not support this feature",
                                                         new UIAlertViewDelegate (), "OK");
                ErrorAlert.Show ();
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //Logging Exception in Flurry
            FA.Flurry.LogError(ex.GetType().Name,ex.Message,
                               new NSError(NSError.CocoaErrorDomain,3584));
            this.ShowErrorInProcessingAlertView ();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890003/uiimagepicker-get-error-snapshotting-a-view-that-has-not-been-rendered-results help you at all?

Comment: I had implemented above solution in Xamarin.ios and tested but sometimes it is not generating error and sometimes not.I have tested it lot more times.

Answer (score 3):

To fix this problem in iOS 7, this is what solved my same error.

When I present the `UIImagePickerController` which in my case is called `imagePickerController`

Do not use **nil** or **NULL**.  Instead, I used the below code and the error no longer appears when opening the camera.

```
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:^{....}];
```

Comment: It didn't help me. I still get the 'Snapshotting a view...' message from time to time :/

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack but sometimes you need something initialized at some time in the lifecycle for interaction reasons or whatever. So what I did is just dispatched it after 0.1 seconds on the view it sits in and it seemed to work okay. Looking more into this.

```
    double delayInSeconds = 0.1;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
     // Show camera view controller.
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];


});
```

Hope this helps till someone finds a much better solution.

Comment: It didn't help me. I still get the 'Snapshotting a view...' message camera load

Answer (score -1):

Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot same error.

This is definitely a bug and you can find this in apple developer forums as well.

I have tried to avoid this error using lot of other answers on stack overflow but could not fix this issue. However using this I could some how not get this error, i would not call this a fix, But give it a try and let me know if it had fixed the issue.
Dismiss the view controller using the Grand Central Dispatch async from the main queue fixed the issue for me.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker     didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

// Code to handle the image data 

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
});
}
-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

});

}
```