# cordova camera plugin not working in ios 8.1

Tags: cordova, ios8, cordova-plugins, ios-camera

Currently i am developing cordova(3.6) application running on ios 8.1.

Cameraplugin always returns the error message given below.

```
THREAD WARNING: ['Camera'] took '613.226807' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.


Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The first line: it's not an error, it's a warning. And it's pretty harmless, but the fix is easy too (it's in plugin development documentation).

The second line: It seems like it's a warning as well. I did a google search and got this:
[iOS 8 Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884801/ios-8-snapshotting-a-view-that-has-not-been-rendered-results-in-an-empty-snapsho)