# Parse not returning a list of usernames

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I cannot for some reason get the username i typed to display in my tableview. Any ideas? I triple checked the name of my cell, the name of class on parse and the name of the column. Maybe i forgot something?

```
import UIKit

import Parse




class AddFriendViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,    UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

@IBOutlet var myFriendSearchBar: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet var myFriendSearchList: UITableView!


var searchResult = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Nexa Rust Script L", size: 25)!,  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
    self.myFriendSearchBar.delegate = self


    self.navigationItem.title = "Haffla"
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
 {
    return searchResult.count
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    myCell.textLabel?.text = searchResult[indexPath.row]

    return myCell

}
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    myFriendSearchBar.resignFirstResponder()

    let userName = PFQuery(className: "User")
    userName.whereKey("username", containsString: searchBar.text)
    let query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([userName])


    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in


        if error != nil {

            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)


            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)


            myAlert.addAction(okAction)

            self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return
        }
        if let friends = objects as [PFObject]? {
            self.searchResult.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

            for object in friends {


                let username = object.objectForKey("username") as! String
                self.searchResult.append(username)


            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.myFriendSearchList.reloadData()
                self.myFriendSearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
            }

        }



    }

}






func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    myFriendSearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    myFriendSearchBar.text? = ""
}



}
```

i got this error:**Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.**

Comment: Try `username.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock...`

Comment: Did you set delegate and dataSource for your tableview to AddFriendViewController?

Comment: that did not work :/ @CleverError

Comment: i got this error: Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates. @Moriya

Comment: Seems like a strange error for this post but check out this link. It might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884801/ios-8-snapshotting-a-view-that-has-not-been-rendered-results-in-an-empty-snapsho

Comment: I am not trying to take a snapshot, maybe i hit the wrong button. Between what button is the function: searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) @Moriya

Comment: I'm afraid I can not help you. I haven't used parse myself and the only thing I can see that might be wrong is the delegate and data source for table view. Perhaps you can try to set them in code and see if that might help.

Comment: i found it!!!! i was looking at the wrong Parse class and i should refer to the user parse class with: var something: PFQuery = PFUser.query()! @Moriya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it!!!! i was looking at the wrong Parse class and i should refer to the user parse class with:

```
var something: PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
```