# Taking a photo results in an app crash with no error message

Tags: ios, swift, ios-camera

As soon as I press the button to take a photo, the app crashes with no error message. The only log messages I get are as follows:

```
2016-02-17 23:29:47.773 OMC[254:4325] Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.
2016-02-17 23:29:49.449 OMC[254:4325] Received memory warning.
```

I can post any relevant code, but I'm not sure what would be of use here.

Comment: have u manage camera permision off or on....!!!

Comment: @yagneshdobariya the camera permission is correct as this worked several days ago, but much has changed in the meantime

Comment: `Received memory warning` --> this error comes arrives in many sceanrios, like your app may be increase the more memory else your device has less memory space , in which device are you tried this

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I was testing on an iPhone 4S when this happened.

Comment: for that first error see this link may be it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884801/ios-8-snapshotting-a-view-that-has-not-been-rendered-results-in-an-empty-snapsho

Comment: I expected this answer , try once in iphone 5s (32 GB ) or iphone 6 (32 gb) or above

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik That appears to work, but how can I be sure that it will work on iPhone 4S / 5?

Comment: It would be just for memory constraint .... look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure it will work for you .

**on your app**

you are just using too much memory `didReceiveMemoryWarning` gets called , Check the Memory of each objects , Another cause is bad usage of memory. It is possible that you are creating objects and holding on to them with a strong reference for longer than you need to. Without seeing your code it's hard to tell where you are doing this. If you dont need the particular object release the memory manually like in `ViewWillDisappear` or in every time refresh.

**on your Device**

Clear the unwanted messages, songs or videos or else whatever you think like it is unwanted delete them and free up your device and try once , may be it helps.

Comment: I found a place where I could release a bunch of memory.Thanks for the help!