# Imagepicker using camera have not use camera image

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Using `UIImagePickerController` have to pick image from library or camera. Library image picking worked without issues but camera image picking have issues. when i select camera option camera opened and took picture. after took picture log displayed as "Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.". when i click use photo button app crashed.

`UIImagePickerController` presentation is

```
let ImagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
ImagePicker.delegate = self
self.presentViewController(ImagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Can you add more code?

Comment: snapshotting a view that has not been rendered ... this error is mostly show in simulator only , and make sure you are getting image from "- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info
" Method

Comment: i got this issue in iphone 6 and ipad 2 also

Answer (score 0):

It looks like bug because many developer get same error and have solution below that works for many developer.Hope any one of solution from following link will help to you..

[iOS 8 Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884801/ios-8-snapshotting-a-view-that-has-not-been-rendered-results-in-an-empty-snapsho)