# Swift - Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot

Tags: ios, swift

My var:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
```

Take photo function:

```
func takePhoto(){
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()

        picker.delegate = self
        picker.sourceType = .Camera

        presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Error message:

> Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty
>   snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before
>   snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates

Any ideas?

Comment: When do you call take a photo? i.e. view did load or view did appear?

Comment: @MitchellCurrie - On button action.

Comment: And where are you actually taking a snapshot? I do not see the code to snapshot the view.

Comment: What do you mean? I dont have a code for snaphot?

Comment: A snapshot is rendering a UIView to an image. Are you using any presentation controller or transition/animation frameworks? show us the code for presentViewController

Comment: @MitchellCurrie - There is no other code, that is all code i used. All i used was this: http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/take-photo-tutorial-ios8-swift

Comment: Are you running this on device or simulator?

Comment: What exactly happens, does the picker come up at all? or does it start to transition. I would suspect you are not on the main thread except your IBAction should be triggered there, is this correct?

Comment: Well, everything works actually, but the error just keeps coming.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890003/uiimagepickercontroller-error-snapshotting-a-view-that-has-not-been-rendered-re

Comment: @MitchellCurrie - Anything for swift? I have never used Obj-C.

Comment: It's probably nothing to worry about at this stage of your learning, but if you wish to dive deeper, try changing the order of page appearances or presenting it in a different modal style. I repeat, just double check this is all happening from main thread (thread 0)

Comment: @MitchellCurrie Hehe, i did not really understand that..

Comment: My advice, ignore it and move on - come back once you understand more. It will make sense.

Comment: @MitchellCurrie Yea i´ll just do that :)

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem - I have two options once I have called the VC - From Photos or Selfie - and when I select Selfie i.e. camera Xcode prints that message but not ion I select Photos - so my guess is its a bug in the camera app.
It has never crashed my app so I ignore it Code:

```
@IBAction func openCameraButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) == true {
        camera = true
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else{
        noCamera()

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it, could you explain more while giving feedback on the OP please ?

Comment: I segue to a VC which has  an Image view and a toolbar with 2 options  one to get a photo from a library and the other to use the camera. The only time I get the warning  when I select the camera and the camera app has loaded:

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have:

```
super.viewDidLoad()
```

in your viewDidLoad func.

Answer (score 1):

put your `self.presentViewController` or your `self.navigationController?.showViewController` inside   `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {`

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
  self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. I would restart XCode and double check your didFinishPickingImage method to make sure it's closing properly. The issue could be with your transitions. This has happened to me several times in the past and never became a big deal.

Comment: This is my "didFinishPackingImage" method: http://pastebin.com/Zyrpu0sL - Do you see anything wrong here?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Are you getting an error with it? Or is the issue the original question?

Comment: I get that warning error from the original question.

Comment: Have you checked the camera permissions in device settings?

Comment: If your camera can be accessed to take a photo.

Comment: As i said; everything works, but still that errors comes.

Comment: I would just ignore for now...doesn't seem to be a real issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably assigning it to another UIImageView too fast, try to save it in another variable first and in the func ViewDidLoad put that image into the UIImageView. That worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

goto setting -> privacy -> camera and enable or disable camera access for individual apps

This issue seems to occur when the key: "CFBundleDisplayName" has an empty string value in the Info.plist.