# UIImagePicker Controller swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

> Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty
>   snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before
>   snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates

I'm getting this warning when I used UIImagePickerController to take photo from camera.and couldn't set image to image view

Comment: I think this older post answers your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890003/uiimagepickercontroller-error-snapshotting-a-view-that-has-not-been-rendered-re

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the code and apply in your project according to the relevant place

```
func openCamera()
{
    if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera))
    {
        picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        self .presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        let alertWarning = UIAlertView(title:"Warning", message: "You don't have camera", delegate:nil, cancelButtonTitle:"OK", otherButtonTitles:"")
        alertWarning.show()
    }
}
func openGallary()
{
    picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    self.presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//PickerView Delegate Methods
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject])
{
    picker .dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    imageView.image=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController)
{
    println("picker cancel.")
}
```